# Execute an event at exactly midnight of the 1st day of every month

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, task-scheduler

I am using Windows XP as OS in my machine. I need to execute an event at exactly midnight of the 1st day of every month. e.g.: 2011-05-01 12:00 AM.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this Microsoft Support article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).